# how to pass a actionListener as parameter in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, modal-dialog

I Have the same code in every page so there is a way to pass as parameter the actionListener ?

```
    <p:confirmDialog widgetVar="deleteDialog" showEffect="fade" width="500" message="Deseja apagar o registro selecionado?" header="Confirmar" severity="warn">
    <p:commandButton value="Sim" icon="pi pi-check" actionListener="#{cargoController.excluir}" process="@this" update="@form" oncomplete="PF('deleteDialog').hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-button-danger" icon="pi pi-times" onclick="PF('deleteDialog').hide()" style="margin-left: 30px" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: Something like this? `<ui:param name="pageController" value="#{randomController}"/>` and then using `#{pageController.importantMethod}`

Comment: TKS It worked in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ui:param name="pageController" value="#{randomController}"/>
```

its work for me